# Обработка формы нажатием кнопки в частичном прелставлении ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Как можно сгенерировать форму в представление из контроллера? Заранее спасибо и можно пожалуйста пример как это реализовать

В моем представлении имеется форма, она обрабатывается ajax запросом и ответ выводится с помощью частичного представления. В частичном представлении также имеется форма, которую мне нужно обработать. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Вот часть частичного представления, куда выводятся значения:

```
@model Parameters

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <div class="block_content">
        <form asp-action="Calculation" method="post">
            <table align="center" class="content_fields">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h3>Результаты</h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Отношение крутизны характеристики ключевого МДП транзистора к соответствующей характеристике нагрузочного МДП транзистора Kк / Kн = @Model.K
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Отношение wн / lн для нагрузочного МДП транзистора = @Model.wn_ln
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Отношение wk / lk для ключевого МДП транзистора = @Model.wk_lk
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Введите минимально возможные при данной технологии значения lк и wн
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</table>
```

Вот часть частичного представления с формой:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <div class="block_content">
        <form asp-action="Calculation" method="post" onsubmit="return CalculationSize(this)">
            <table align="center" class="content_fields" border-spacing: 7px 11px;>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Длина ключевого транзистора</label>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input asp-for="lk" class="form-control" id="lk"/>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="lk" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Ширина нагрузочного транзистора</label>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input asp-for="wn" class="form-control" id="wn"/>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="wn" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Рассчитать" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</table>

<script src="~/js/Calculation.js"></script>
```

Calculation.js

```
function CalculationSize(form) {
var param = {
    lk: form.lk.value,
    wn: form.wn.value
}
$.get("/Calculation/Calculation", param);
$("#calculationSize").load("/Calculation/GetParametersSize");
return false;
}
```

При нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит

Контроллер:

```
public ActionResult GetParametersSize()
{
    return PartialView("_Calculation", calculationParameters.parameters.Last());
}

public ActionResult Calculation(Parameters pam)
    {
        Parameters parameters = calculationParameters.parameters.Last();
        parameters.lk = pam.lk;
        parameters.wn = pam.wn;
        CalculationOfSize calPam = calPam = new CalculationOfSize(parameters);
        calculationParameters.Calculation(calPam.parameters);
        return View(calPam.parameters);
    }
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Поясните вашу задачу, а в чем у вас с этой задачей проблема? С текущей формулировкой вопрос не имеет смысла, так как в mvc любое представление генерируется из какого то контроллера и чтобы представление генерировало форму нужно просто добавить эту форму в нужное представление.

Comment: Мне нужно в уже имеющееся представление загрузить форму. Просто у меня используется 2 формы, в первую вводятся значения, а во вторую выводится ответ и если я ее вывожу в одном представлении с первой при этом скрываю ее, то получаю ошибку сразу при запуске, т.к. оно требует значение для вывода (а т.к. оно только запущено данных с формы нету)

Comment: [Частичные представления](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/4.5.php)?

Comment: [Ajax-Формы](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/10.4.php)

Comment: Пробывал частиные представления, но не разобрался как вызвать частичное представление после нажатия кнопки

Comment: [Load Partial Views Using Ajax In ASP.NET Core MVC And Razor Pages](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/65cfe9cd-b98f-48b7-825d-31ae8008a91a.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую реализовать

Comment: Может вы знаете как можно обработать форму из частичного предтавления, у меня просто во втрой форме есть кнопка и я ни как не могу обработать форму по ее нажатию

Comment: Где то у вас есть какой то ваш код, вы с ним что то делаете и у вас что то не получается - но вы в вопросе не указали ни одной детали вашей проблемы, ничего. Как я могу понять, что вам надо сделать, что вы делаете и какие результаты получаете? У меня нет такой информации, гадать я не буду, потому помочь не могу ничем.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120991/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-asp-net-core

Comment: Вы создали дубликат своего вопроса. Не надо так. Просто поправьте этот вопрос, вы же можете его редактировать.

Comment: И непонятно, что вы из второй формы обрабатывать собрались? Там нет ни полей ввода, ни кнопок.

Comment: Я поправил вопрос